# Android Expandable List Put Child Items From String Array

Tags: android, expandablelistview, arrays

I'm trying to make an Expandable List in Android. But I have one problem putting the values in child list.

Group list data I'm writing manually because they won't be changed. But Child list data will be generated from my SQLite database (takeItemsFromDatabase() method is taking data from database and it puts to "product" array string).

So the array String "Product" got all items.

My problem is starting right here. When I'm trying to put array String "product" into child list, in this way:

```
static final String hijosGrupos[][] = {
        // Shades of grey
        {product},
        // Shades of blue
        { "example 1", "example 2", "etc" }, {}, {}, {}, {}};
```

It gives me this error:

```
"Type mismatch: cannot convert from String[] to String"
```

I know why it shows me an error but I don't know how to resolve it.

So basically I want to put data from some column of my database to child list.

Any one got some idea?

Here is my code:

```
public class Resumen extends ExpandableListActivity {

String[] preguntasContrato;
String[] especiesDetectadas;
String[] medidasEstructurales;
String[] medidasSobreHabitos;
String[] medidasControlDirecto;
static String[] product;

String Grupos[] = { "Product", "Preguntas contrato", "Others",
        "Medidas 1", "Medidas 2",
        "Medidas 3", "Medidas 4" };

    //Here are values of child lists
static final String hijosGrupos[][] = {
        // Shades of grey
        {},
        // Shades of blue
        { "example 1", "example 2", "etc" }, {}, {}, {}, {}};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.resumenlista);
    Log.i("Prueba", "Prrr");
    cogerProductosSeleccionados();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    SimpleExpandableListAdapterWithEmptyGroups expListAdapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapterWithEmptyGroups(
            this, createGroupList(), R.layout.nombrefilaresumen,
            new String[] { "colorName" }, new int[] { R.id.groupname },
            createChildList(), R.layout.filahijoresumen, new String[] {
                    "shadeName", "rgb" }, new int[] { R.id.childname,
                    R.id.rgb });
    setListAdapter(expListAdapter);

}

@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
private List createGroupList() {
    ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < Grupos.length; ++i) {
        HashMap m = new HashMap();
        m.put("colorName", Grupos[i]);
        result.add(m);
    }
    return (List) result;
}

@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
private List createChildList() {
    ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < hijosGrupos.length; ++i) {
        ArrayList secList = new ArrayList();
        for (int n = 0; n < hijosGrupos[i].length; n += 2) {
            HashMap child = new HashMap();
            child.put("shadeName", hijosGrupos[i][n]);
            child.put("rgb", hijosGrupos[i][n + 1]);
            secList.add(child);
        }
        result.add(secList);
    }
    return result;
}

public void takeItemsFromDatabase() {
    List<String> uGraduateNamesList = new ArrayList<String>();
    AndroidOpenDbHelper openHelperClass = new AndroidOpenDbHelper(this);

    SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase = openHelperClass.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = sqliteDatabase.query("ProductosTemporal", null, null,
            null, null, null, null);

    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

        String descripcionproducto = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(AndroidOpenDbHelper.descripcionproducto));

        uGraduateNamesList.add(descripcionproducto);

        final String[] itemsInArrayString = uGraduateNamesList
                .toArray(new String[uGraduateNamesList.size()]);
        Items(itemsInArrayString);

    }
    cursor.close();
    sqliteDatabase.close();

}

public void Items(String[] itemDesc) {
     product = itemDesc;

}
}
```

[Here](http://androgue.blogspot.com.es/2011/08/android-expandablelistview-tutorial.html) I've found this code.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you are pulling the data for the children from the database, presumably the data for the groups is in there as well (otherwise how would you decide what to pull for each group?).  That being the case, why bother with arrays at all?  Just extend SimpleCursorTreeAdapter and use cursors from your DB to drive the enitre list.  This would have the benefit of not having to change a bit of code relating to the list if you decide to add a new group.

Comment: Hi Barak, I've tried some examples of SimpleCursorTreeAdapter but no one worked. Have you got some good example of SimpleCursorTreeAdapter?.

Answer (score 0):

SimpleCursorAdapter example:

Cursor calls from my dbhelper for the expandablelist :

```
public Cursor fetchGroup(String group) {
    String query = "SELECT DISTINCT "
            + group
            + " AS _id FROM "
            + LISTITEM_TABLE;
    return mDb.rawQuery(query, null);
}

public Cursor fetchChildren(String column, String token) {
    String query = "SELECT _id, name, qty, unit FROM items WHERE "
            + column
            + "='"
            + token
            + "';
     return mDb.rawQuery(query, null);
}
```

Call the adapter:

```
ExpandableListView lv;
mGroupsCursor = mDbHelper.fetchGroup(group,
        ListFragment_ShopList.listId);
getActivity().startManagingCursor(mGroupsCursor);
mGroupsCursor.moveToFirst();

lv = (ExpandableListView) getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
lv.setItemsCanFocus(false);
lv.setChoiceMode(ExpandableListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

mAdapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter(mGroupsCursor, getActivity(),
        R.layout.rowlayout_expgroup, R.layout.rowlayout_itemlist_exp,
        new String[] { "_id" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 },
        new String[] { GroceryDB.ITEM_NAME, GroceryDB.LISTITEM_QTY,
                GroceryDB.ITEM_UNIT }, new int[] { R.id.ListItem1,
                R.id.ListItem3, R.id.ListItem2 });
lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Adapter (in the same .java file as the call for it):

```
public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends SimpleCursorTreeAdapter {
    public MyExpandableListAdapter(Cursor cursor, Context context,
            int groupLayout, int childLayout, String[] groupFrom,
            int[] groupTo, String[] childrenFrom, int[] childrenTo) {
        super(context, cursor, groupLayout, groupFrom, groupTo,
                childLayout, childrenFrom, childrenTo);
    }
    @Override
    protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor groupCursor) {
        Cursor childCursor = mDbHelper.fetchChildren(GroceryListMain.group,
                groupCursor.getString(groupCursor.getColumnIndex("_id")),
                ListFragment_ShopList.listId);
        getActivity().startManagingCursor(childCursor);
        childCursor.moveToFirst();
        return childCursor;
    }
    protected void bindChildView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor,
            boolean isLastChild) {
        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ListItem1);
        TextView qty = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ListItem3);
        TextView unit = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ListItem2);
        name.setText(cursor.getString(1));
        qty.setText(cursor.getString(2));
        unit.setText(cursor.getString(3));
    }
}
```

The biggest thing in all of the above is the `SELECT DISTINCT columnn as _id` in the call for the group cursor... it gives you one record for each *different* grouping, then you use that to fetch the children.